# Prevent closing python IDLE shell by Ctrl+D

Tags: python

I'm using Python IDLE Shell `2.7, 64 bit on win32`.

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Many times I falsely press `Ctrl+D` instead of `Ctrl+F` and `Ctrl+C`, then the shell exit without any prompts. I checked the `keys` in `Configure IDLE`, the key set for `Ctrl+D` was for `end-of-file`. Any way can I prevent such annoying behavior by `Ctrl+D`?

Comment: If you are only just learning Python, you should definitely be looking at Python 3 now.

Comment: @tripleee No, I have used it for two or three years. I got a new computer and installed python 2.7 64bit on this computer. The problem did not occur before when I used python 2.7 32bit. It is strange because the `Ctrl+D` to close a working window only worked in `IDLE Shell`. `Ctrl+D` works as it is designed in IDLE code editor.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing ctrl+D cause EOFError exception in the program. We can put this exception inside a try catch statement and therefore the program will never affected by ctrl+D.

```
try:
  raw_input()
except EOFError:
  pass
```

Comment: The question is about trapping this in IDLE.